# How to create pagination with inline keyboard in telegram

Tags: node.js, pagination, telegram, telegram-bot

I am creating a Telegram bot wit Node.js and I am using node-telegram-bot-api module.

My current issue is:
*To create pagination with inline keyboard.*
In documentation [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/2-0-intro#new-inline-keyboards), has an interesting example of what I need.

For appearances, I must use method **editMessageText** but for update inline keyboard I need to transfer param **inline_message_id**. Unfortunately I could not understand how to do it.

I will be very much appreciate for any example to update inline keyboard and how it release in [this example](https://core.telegram.org/bots/2-0-intro#new-inline-keyboards).

Comment: You have **inline_message_id** only when your bot is used in inline mode (when a user is typing @yourBotNickname into message field). You can edit those buttons if you know **inline_message_id** _or_ **chat_id** + **message_id**. On that sample the message was sent by a bot so you should use **editMessageText** with pair of chat and message ids.

Comment: Thank you very much!  
Through trial and error, I still managed!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need pass updated pagination with `editMessageText`:

```
var bookPages = 100;

function getPagination( current, maxpage ) {
  var keys = [];
  if (current>1) keys.push({ text: `«1`, callback_data: '1' });
  if (current>2) keys.push({ text: `‹${current-1}`, callback_data: (current-1).toString() });
  keys.push({ text: `-${current}-`, callback_data: current.toString() });
  if (current<maxpage-1) keys.push({ text: `${current+1}›`, callback_data: (current+1).toString() })
  if (current<maxpage) keys.push({ text: `${maxpage}»`, callback_data: maxpage.toString() });

  return {
    reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
      inline_keyboard: [ keys ]
    })
  };
}

bot.onText(/\/book/, function(msg) {
  bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, 'Page: 25', getPagination(25,bookPages));
});

bot.on('callback_query', function (message) {
    var msg = message.message;
    var editOptions = Object.assign({}, getPagination(parseInt(message.data), bookPages), { chat_id: msg.chat.id, message_id: msg.message_id});
    bot.editMessageText('Page: ' + message.data, editOptions);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this example!
I can edit this inline keyboard!

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to make pagination in python telegram bot , you can simply use the [pypi.org](https://pypi.org) pakage know as [python-telegram-bot-pagination/](https://pypi.org/project/python-telegram-bot-pagination/)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).