# How to send transparent choice button with telegram bot

Tags: python-2.7, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Using a Telegram Bot, I would like to know how I can send "transparent choice buttons" like in this image.

[image]

I dug in the documentation but here, they only explain how to make custom *keyboard* buttons, in such a way that  the android keyboard pops up with custom buttons in order for the user to choose.

With the ones in the image I uploaded, ( the buttons named "<<", "" and ">>" ) a user could vote or navigate intuitively and not be bothered with custom keyboard.

What is the code I need to send them? Then, when an user presses them, how can I handle the choice?

I'm working with Python and Linux.

Thanks in advance. 
I searched but couldn't find anything.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42874286/how-to-create-pagination-with-inline-keyboard-in-telegram

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardmarkup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is implementing inline keyboards that you can find more information about them [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/2-0-intro).

And for receiving the votes from the users firstly you need a database to store them and secondly you should use callback buttons or callback queries, which are part of inline keyboard markup in telegram bot API.